# Accessing GCE API from my web site

Tags: javascript, python, oauth, google-compute-engine

I am trying to access GCE information in a read only way to display data about an infrastructure on my web site. Basically I want to get an OAuth2 token using JS API and then pass it to a Python Backend to do the API calls to GCE. My site is not hosted on GCE at all.

I get however confused in the proper way to set this up. I have created a Google application so it can ask for the authorizations and ask for access to the GCE APIs. I did start from the sample available at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/source/browse/samples/authSample.html. However each time I do run the sample I get an error in the first phase of the authorization process, mentioning an error due to 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Trying to isolate the error and comparing with running the Google sample from my site, it seems this is purely linked to the settings of my app (basically the google sample with my app ID does not work ) and I get lost in how to debug this process. Is there any methodology that could be applied here?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Are you able to post the HTTP request/response you get when you go through the auth process

Answer (score 0):

The sample you are following is for retrieving a profile in Google Plus, using the '[Public API key](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#apikey)'. This type of key is used only to retrieve public data. If you want to access information on GCE, you must use [OAuth 2.0](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/authorization) to authorize requests. For implementing this, you have different scenarios as [web server, installed app, client-side (JS)](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2), etc.